# How can I reverse the movement of my pseudo element transition?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

So I'm trying to make this button animation while learning about pseudo-elements and I'm really close to achieving what I want but there's something that really bugs me.

This is what I have currently: https://codepen.io/saifeldeenadel/pen/xxPwvdj?editors=1100

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: calc(50vh - 40px);
}

#btn {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13pt;
  border: 0px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}

#btn:hover {
  color: black
}

#btn::before {
  content: '';
  background: #333333;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0; 
  z-index: -1;
  transition: height 0.2s ease-in;
}

#btn:hover::before {
  height: 0%;
}
```

Looks pretty good. But what I want is for the background to go from top to bottom rather than bottom to top. Every way I try to manipulate it, it results in me ruining the whole thing, for example trying to set the background of the button element to the dark grey and having the pseudo-element be the white results in the element completely covering the text and so ruining the effect, etc.

So if you have any idea please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: calc(50vh - 40px);
}

#btn {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13pt;
  border: 0px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}

#btn:hover {
  color: black
}

#btn::before {
  content: '';
  background: #333333;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0; 
  z-index: -1;
  transition: height 0.2s ease-in;
}

#btn:hover::before {
  height: 0%;
}
```

```html
<button id='btn'>know more </button>
```

In `#btn::before` cancel `top: 0` and add `bottom: 0` then it should work as you want

Comment: Thats insane, thank you, but I don't understand why it works. Would you mind explaining it a bit?

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches to this, you could use `transition: top 0.2s ease-in;`
instead of `height` transition.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: calc(50vh - 40px);
}

#btn {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13pt;
  border: 0px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}

#btn:hover {
  color: black
}

#btn::before {
  content: '';
  background: #333333;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0; 
  z-index: -1;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in;
}

#btn:hover::before {
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button id='btn'>know more </button>
```